# Color and size using Nativescript icomon font in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

Can't change the color and size of icons with icomon in CSS. I'm using Nativescript core.

CSS:

```
.moon {
    font-family: "icomoon";
    font-size: 40;
    color: black;
}
```

XML:

```
<label text="&#xf000;" class="fa test"></label> 
<label text="&#xe900;"  style="color: black; font-size: 40" class="moon"></label>
```

The second label works fine with inline style, but I need to do that with CSS like the first label. It load the icon, but not the other styles.

Comment: Does that work if you remove font-family from css? If not then the css is not getting loaded. try to create a playground example which will help you fixing issues or getting help. I dont think it would need unit as mentioned by @Pete.

Comment: I said that because I have seen in Nativescript the css font size work without unit. For example: Check css files here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=Y4fVGt&v=16

Comment: yes Nativescript have a deffault unit (dip). @Rakesh It doesn't works without the font-family and I don't know how can unpload fonts to playground (I'm very ner on NativeScript).  In the inline style version works fine without units.

Comment: You can upload the font to playground. Go to https://play.nativescript.org/ Click on + button and Create Folder named Fonts under app button and then again click on + folder and upload resource browse to ttf file and upload. try nativescript playground, its cool easy and you will love it.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the "+" thanks. It seems that on playground works fine but in local run mode doesn't works for me. could I need some aditional Config? I'm using the blank template. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=NdW0SF

Comment: @Pete he is using NativeScript where the default unit size are unitless and are DIP for iOS and Android

Comment: Um If I put the code outside of my carousel it works fine... Are there any kind of !important for CSS in NativeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problen with another plugin that overrides my label styles.

Comment: which plugin was that?

Comment: it was this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-slides, but I had to remove android and add it again, probably some residual CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<Label text="&#xe900;" color = "black" fontSize = "40" fontFamily = "icomoon"></Label>
```